# Cannot solve Ubongo Extreme B37 yellow puzzle

Tags: board-games, jigsaw-puzzle

How can we solve the yellow B-37 puzzle?
[image: B-37]

Ubongo Extreme rules recap: Rearrange the pieces so they form the shape given on the card, with no holes and no overlap. Flipping pieces over (to turn a piece into its mirror image) is allowed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, you'll need to

> flip every piece except the 11

and then they'll fit:

> [image]

Solution method:

The most constrained piece is very likely going to be the 11: it has a deep notch that won't fit any part of the edge, so it has to be filled by another piece. This increases the probability that the opposing side of the 11 is going to end up being on the edge of the shape. There are only a couple of places along the edge where the long side of the 11-piece will fit snugly, and indeed one of those allows us to place the rest of the pieces.

Comment: I found the same solution - you were faster :). Do you think the solution is unique?

Comment: I'd guess it is (because it's pretty hard to find any solution here), but of course I haven't ruled out every possibility.

Comment: I also tried all positions for the 11 and only one leads to a solution.